# How to compare strings within a list-of-lists?

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have the following list

`lst =[['A', 'BA'], ['B', 'CB'], ['C', 'AC'], ['D', 'ED']]`.

I want to check if the first element in a given list is found in the second element of the previous list. If that is the case then take the second element of the list and add it to the second element in the previous list.

**Eg.**
`'B'` is found in `'BA'`, therefore the first list should look like this `['A', 'BACB']`.

I have tried different things, but the following is the closest to the desired result:

```py
for i, j in enumerate(lst[1:]):
    if ''.join((set(j[0])).intersection(lst[i][1])):
        lst[i][1] += j[1]

> output: [['A', 'BACB'], ['B', 'CBAC'], ['C', 'AC'], ['D', 'ED']]
```

The **desired** result looks like this:

```py
[['A', 'BACB'], ['B', 'CBAC'], ['C', 'ACBACB'], ['D', 'ED']]
```

Comment: As far as I understand your description, `['C', 'AC']` should only be modified if "D" from the following (last) list would be in "AC", but it isn't.

Comment: @mudi From your description of the task, it makes no sense that the desired list has `['C','ACBACB']`. It looks like we only add to a string at most once, and the string that's added has at most two characters, so the second elements of each pair should have either 2 or 4 characters

Comment: @mudi When you say "a previous list", do you mean **any** of the lists that come before the given list or only the list immediately before the given list?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Correct, I mean any of the lists that come before. The reason that the desired list should have `['C','ACBACB']` is because the list originally contains 'AC' and since 'C' is in `['A', 'BACB']` the 'BACB' gets added to it. I hope this clarifies my logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear whether the following code can cover all test cases.

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
lst = [['A', 'BA'], ['B', 'CB'], ['C', 'AC'], ['D', 'ED']]
# lst_map = dict(lst)
lst_map = {i[0]: i[1] for i in lst}
for k, v in lst_map.items():
    for c in v:
        if c != k:
            lst_map[k] += lst_map.get(c, "")
result = [[k, v] for k, v in lst_map.items()]
print(result)
# Output [['A', 'BACB'], ['B', 'CBAC'], ['C', 'ACBACB'], ['D', 'ED']]
```